# TextField inside Wrap throws "The _RenderDecoration class does not support dry layout"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dialog

I need a **TextField** inside **Wrap** widget. But it throws this error,

> The _RenderDecoration class does not support dry layout
>
> ....
>
> ....
>
> ════════ Exception caught by scheduler library ════════
>
> Updated layout information required
> for RenderFlex#87b02 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT to
> calculate semantics.

The Parent of the Wrap widget is a **Column** with mainAxisSize.min. And the Column is inside an **AlertDialog**'s content. And also I need dynamic height. So, I didn't use any fixed height **SizedBox**.
Here is the code example,

```
AlertDialog(
  scrollable: true,
  content: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      SomeWidgets(),
      Wrap(
        spacing: 5,
        runSpacing: 5,
        crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(t.someText),
          Container(
            width: 50.0,
            height: 50.0,
            color: theme.colorScheme.primary,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              controller: _controller,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 5),
                isDense: true,
                filled: true,
              ),
              onChanged: (v) {},
            ),
          ),
          Text(t.someText),
        ],
      ),
      SomeWidgets(),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: What is the parent widget of wrap

Comment: Column with mainAxisSize.min

Comment: Everything is working fine, Can you include minimal widget from scaffold body.

Comment: It is inside a AlertDialog's Content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `Wrap` widget with `Flexible` or provide height on `wrap` widget inside dialog.

On `scrollable: false` use `SingleChildScrollView` for dynamic height

```dart
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (c) => AlertDialog(
          scrollable: false,
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: Wrap(
```

Comment: No. It is not working.

Comment: Consider including [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from showDialog that will reproduce the error

Comment: I need dynamic height.

Comment: use `scrollable: false,` with  `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: if I use scrollable: false and SingleChildScrollView then the size of the AlertDialog will be Screen height.

Comment: I am using `SingleChildScrollView` on Column, if the children gets bigger it will be scrollable else not, And dialog wont get bigger if the content is smaller, try testing yourself

Answer (score 1):

It is a flutter bug. [Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71687#issuecomment-753549590) is the solution.

**Essential parts**:
As long as Flutter's implementation of TextField blows up during dry layout, the only way we can avoid the bug is to prevent the dry layout call from being invoked on TextField.

We came up with slight alterations on IntrinsicWidth and IntrinsicHeight that use the child's intrinsic dimensions instead of invoking the child's dry layout method:
https://gist.github.com/matthew-carroll/65411529a5fafa1b527a25b7130187c6

Then you can do something like:

```
Wrap(
  children: [
    DryIntrinsicWidth(
      child: TextField(...),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34724906)

Answer (score 0):

Add `Flexible` inside `Column`.

Reference : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html

```
AlertDialog(
    content: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
  Flexible( // Added
      child: Wrap(
    spacing: 5,
    runSpacing: 5,
    crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
    children: []
    ))
    ])
```

Comment: No, It is not working.

Comment: I have checked in my PC and its working. You have to add your full code instead of small part of code.

Comment: Updated the code. Please check.